# How to parse user credentials from URL in C#?

Tags: c#, parsing, url

I have a link in this format:

```
http://user:pass@example.com
```

How to get `user` and `pass` from this URL?

Comment: What have you actually tried? What was the expected result? If you didn't get the result you expected, what did you actually get? Sorry, this is not a "give me teh codez" site - please read the FAQ if that is unclear.

Comment: From the FAQ: _"You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face."_ and _"We’re all here to learn together. Be tolerant of others who may not know everything you know."_

Comment: Better question is how to remove it :P

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Uri class has a UserInfo attribute.

```
Uri uriAddress = new Uri ("http://user:password@www.contoso.com/index.htm ");
Console.WriteLine(uriAddress.UserInfo);
```

The value returned by this property is usually in the format "userName:password".

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.userinfo.aspx

Comment: This only works if there is NOT an "@" symbol in the credentials (common for usernames that are email addresses, or in strong passwords).

Comment: True. Note that '@' is a reserved character in the Uniform Resource Identifier, specified by the RFC. See https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#page-12 As you can see there are a lot of characters, when contained in a username or a password that make the URI invalid.

Comment: Yeah, when we did this, we ended up parsing out the credentials and using HttpUtility.UrlEncode on them before adding them back. Windows Explorer will accept un-encoded credentials (which is where our users are copying/pasting them into our app). Also, UriBuilder does not encode them when it builds the URI. I would expect a "builder" to handle things like that; it's annoying to have to parse stuff before passing it off to a parser. :)

Answer (score 6):

I took this a little farther and wrote some URI extensions to **split username and password.** Wanted to share my solution.

```
public static class UriExtensions
{
    public static string GetUsername(this Uri uri)
    {
        if (uri == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uri.UserInfo))
            return string.Empty;

        var items = uri.UserInfo.Split(new[] { ':' });
        return items.Length > 0 ? items[0] : string.Empty;
    }

    public static string GetPassword(this Uri uri)
    {
        if (uri == null || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(uri.UserInfo))
            return string.Empty;

        var items = uri.UserInfo.Split(new[] { ':' });
        return items.Length > 1 ? items[1] : string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Comment: Missed@ domain parsing

Comment: We often need both at the same time https://gist.github.com/duongphuhiep/13f104e4229bf7e1869921e034834ec6